# Cannot connect to MySQL in Python program

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, mysql-python, mysql-error-1045

I am trying to establish a connection with a MySQL database in a python program

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='admin',
    password='admin1234',
    database='meu_banco'
)
cnx.close()

print(cnx)
```

but keep getting the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Im am pretty sure that the username is admin and that I've setted 'admin1234' as the password. Anyone knows what might be happening?

Notes:

-I've also tried to use 'passwd' and 'db' instead of 'password' and 'database' keyword arguments.

-I'm using MySQL that comes with XAMPP version 8.0.2 / PHP 8.0.2 for Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am pretty sure the username is admin". Did you set the username as admin or you are guessing it is admin? PS: As the error says, it looks like an error resulting from invalid credentials...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the inaccurate explanation. I meant that wrong credentials are not the cause of the problem. I am 100% sure that e set the username and password as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to the database and afterwards you are closing the connection.

Only use `cnx.close()` when you want to close the database connection, it may cause an error.

If that's not the problem, you may have the user wrong, try to use the default username that MySQL Workbench has, it is `root`.